# How to make eplilog text visible while exporting plot as pdf?

Tags: plotting, export, image-processing, image

I am having this problem that if I add some epilog text in a plot  by rotating it, then while I export the plot as pdf, the text becomes invisible. It works fine if I export it as jpeg or png.
What might be the problem and how to resolve it ?

For example :

```
chck = Plot[{y == 1}, {x, 1, 15}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  Epilog -> {Rotate[
     Text[Style["DSDBVKJFSDVBKJS", 28, Bold], 
      Scaled[{0.3, 0.6}]], -48 Degree]}, ImageSize -> 800];
Export["chck.pdf", chck];
```

Now, in the pdf file the text does not appear fully.

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your `Export` issue (for me it does work), but try to move `Rotate` to `chck = Plot[{y == 1}, {x, 1, 15}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Rotate[Style["DSDBVKJFSDVBKJS", 28, Bold], -48 Degree], Scaled[{0.3, 0.6}]]}, ImageSize -> 800]`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am not sure of the reason though.

Comment: Your code worked for me without changes. However, in such strange cases, I usually solved many problems by wrapping the expression with `Rasterize[Here stays your Plot statement, RasterSize->size]` before exporting. Just play with the value of the parameter "size" between 300 and 1000 to ensure the image quality.

Comment: Thanks, Andrzej.  Your suggestion to move the Rotate worked for me also.

Comment: The replacement of Rotate didn't work for me while using Mathematica 13.3.

Comment: However, if the rotation is about 90º there is no problem at all.